# How do we connect our math.stackexchange account to our facebook page???

Tags: discussion, soft-question

For instance,  I would like to display on my FB page that I have an active account here.  Is there some 1-click way of doing that?  Has anybody done this?  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I looked through "Update info" on FB, and there's not an obvious way to do that.

Comment: Maybe more appropriate for meta-stackexchange than here

Comment: Last I checked you could put in a list of websites you have. You could add a link to your StackExchange profile page there.

Comment: Actually if my memory is not correct, when you sign up on SE, you are given the choice to link/use accounts to login right? Or is that not the same thing?

Comment: @Nameless Logging in with facebook is not the same thing as showing your SE rep on facebook.

Comment: I searched a little whether there are some related post on meta.SO, but I only found this (maybe someone will find something more relevant there): [Displaying Flair on my Facebook Timeline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131691/displaying-flair-on-my-facebook-timeline) and [How can I share my Stack Overflow reputation on Facebook?] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141300/how-can-i-share-my-stack-overflow-reputation-on-facebook).

Comment: @MartinSleziak the MO Meta post was helpful, but then *where* do I place the flair.  I tried copy / paste into a blog post on FB and that didn't work.  But I need a permanent spot on the page anyway...